# Finding all openGL calls in iOS instruments

Tags: ios, opengl-es, instruments

I am trying to profile and optimize iOS app that uses openGL.  I am using the Time Profiler tool to see which methods are taking the most time.  I want to filter the results so that I only see methods, and their callers, that use OpenGLES.  Is there a way to do this?

I see something called "Specific Data Mining", but I don't understand what it does.

Comment: Have you looked through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/Performance/Performance.html already?  It might give you better ideas on optimizing your openGL

Answer (score 0):

The Time Profiler instrument isn't designed to profile OpenGL ES code. Apple provides separate instruments for profiling OpenGL ES code. Use the OpenGL ES Analyzer template to profile your app's OpenGL ES usage. The template includes both the OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument and the OpenGL ES Driver instrument.